# How to retrieve all users from firebase to only one textview in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have got a firebase database where I have got a list of users. All users are listed under this child called Users. Each user has 3 childs as follows:
email
name
age

What i want now is to retrieve only emails to only one textview.

I mean all emails of the users to one textview, separated by comma, each email after another.

I do not want to use listview, I have a textview where i want the emails to show as follows:

email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com,  email3@gmail.com

I do not know where to start from, how can I do this?

Comment: there are numerous examples available online for retrieving data from firebase, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess appending the values would solve your issue :

- Append Your values with textView

```
myTextView.append( email + ",");
```

- if you want each email in different line you can do this

```
 myTextView.append( email + ","  + "\n");
```